# Where to learn about pseudoisotopy space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

What is known about homotopy groups of the space of smooth pseudoisotopies of a closed simply-connected manifold $M$? (I am also interested in manifolds with finite fundamental group).

Is there a survey on the subject (written after Igusa's stability paper of 1988)?

I am mostly interested in computations that go beyond Cerf's theorem and Igusa's stability theorem. For example, what is known when $M$ is a sphere, or sphere bundle over $CP^n$?

Comment: I don't know of any computations that lie beyond Igusa's stable range, except when the manifold has dimension $\le 3$. But there are ways of detecting some nontrivial homotopy classes in higher dimensions.

Comment: I am mostly interested in higher dimensions and I do not have a firm grip on consequences of Igusa's stability theorem. Is there an expository account on what is known in the stable range?

Comment: A survey of these matters is "Automorphisms of manifolds" by Michael Weiss and Bruce Williams, see http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0012101 even though it does not (seem to) contain the computations I need.